# How to wrap rows of second entry of QFormLayout?Actual and Expected result images are attached

Tags: qt, qlabel, qlayout, qformlayout

I am using QFormLayout but second item of row is not getting vertically wrapped.

.ui file content is

```
   <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
          <property name="widgetResizable">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
           <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
             <x>0</x>
             <y>0</y>
             <width>524</width>
             <height>281</height>
            </rect>
           </property>
           <layout class="QFormLayout" name="flPatientInfo">
            <property name="rowWrapPolicy">
             <enum>QFormLayout::WrapLongRows</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="verticalSpacing">
             <number>5</number>
            </property>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
```

Code where row is added -

```
  for (auto info : patientInfo.toStdMap())
  {
    QLabel *fieldData = new QLabel(GetTranslatedString(info.second.second));
    fieldData->setProperty("FieldData", true);
    m_GUI->m_UI->flPatientInfo->addRow(GetTranslatedString(info.second.first), fieldData); 
  }
```

Actual Result
[image: Actual Result]

Expected Result
[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 0):

[`QFormLayout::RowWrapPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qformlayout.html#RowWrapPolicy-enum) has to do how labels and the widgets are layed out, not if the widgets should break. If the space available for label + widget is not sufficient, the widget is simply layed out in a new row when using `QFormLayout::WrapLongRows`.

You add a `QLabel` as the widget, which usually will not break text, but write in a single line. You need to enable word wrap on that label using [`setWordWrap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#wordWrap-prop):

```
for (auto info : patientInfo.toStdMap())
{
    QLabel *fieldData = new QLabel(GetTranslatedString(info.second.second));
    fieldData->setProperty("FieldData", true);
    fieldData->setWordWrap(true); // HERE
    m_GUI->m_UI->flPatientInfo->addRow(GetTranslatedString(info.second.first), fieldData); 
}
```

Comment: Added  fieldData->setWordWrap(true) , but getting same actual result.

Comment: I see, you have your form layout inside a scroll area. In that case the word wrap doesn't work as usual. I will try to find another solution